# EM/Microwave interaction with neutral atoms and their particles

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, atoms, microwaves

I'm not sure I understand this well, so please bear with me. I've read a few answers on here about electric fields from neutral atoms, but they aren't agreeing on it. In any case, these are the questions I have:

1. When EM waves and for example microwaves interact with neutral atoms, do they interact with the protons and electrons inside?
2. If 1 is true, can atoms be heated up by the vibration due to the EM field interacting with the protons and electrons?
3. If 2 is true, why aren't nonpolar molecules or neutral atoms heated up by a typical household microwave.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

1. Yes, EM waves interact with neutral atoms through their constituent particles.
2. Yes, this interaction tends to deliver energy and thus heat them up.
3. Nonpolar molecules and neutral atoms *do* get heated up, it's just less efficient than the heat transferred to the water content.

Comment: By less efficient you mean the subatomic particles heating up is negligible compared to polar molecules?